# How to parse XML in slice format

Tags: xml, go, unmarshalling

I have this XML:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ASCII"?><QuestionFormAnswers xmlns="http://mechanicalturk.amazonaws.com/AWSMechanicalTurkDataSchemas/2005-10-01/QuestionFormAnswers.xsd"><Answer><QuestionIdentifier>annotatedResult.boundingBoxes</QuestionIdentifier><FreeText>[{"height":641,"label":"F-22 Raptor","left":82,"top":97,"width":1088}]</FreeText></Answer><Answer><QuestionIdentifier>annotatedResult.inputImageProperties.height</QuestionIdentifier><FreeText>839</FreeText></Answer><Answer><QuestionIdentifier>annotatedResult.inputImageProperties.width</QuestionIdentifier><FreeText>1260</FreeText></Answer></QuestionFormAnswers>
```

I dont know how to parse to get `[{"height":641,"label":"F-22 Raptor","left":82,"top":97,"width":1088}]`  and get individual values such as `height`, `weight`, and etc. Finally getting `641, 82, 97` and `1088`

I tried this based on the guides I found:

```
type DimensionInfo struct {

    Answer  struct {
    FreeText []string `xml:"freetext"`
    } `xml:"answer"`
}


var data = []byte(`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ASCII"?><QuestionFormAnswers xmlns="http://mechanicalturk.amazonaws.com/AWSMechanicalTurkDataSchemas/2005-10-01/QuestionFormAnswers.xsd"><Answer><QuestionIdentifier>annotatedResult.boundingBoxes</QuestionIdentifier><FreeText>[{"height":641,"label":"F-22 Raptor","left":82,"top":97,"width":1088}]</FreeText></Answer><Answer><QuestionIdentifier>annotatedResult.inputImageProperties.height</QuestionIdentifier><FreeText>839</FreeText></Answer><Answer><QuestionIdentifier>annotatedResult.inputImageProperties.width</QuestionIdentifier><FreeText>1260</FreeText></Answer></QuestionFormAnswers>`) 

var t DimensionInfo
xml.Unmarshal(data, &t)
fmt.Println(t.Answer.FreeText)
```

I'm getting empty slice/list

Comment: Don't _ever_ ignore errors. If you'll check error from `xml.Unmarshal`, you'll see the reason it does not unmarshal your data.

Comment: That's the first problem. The second one is that for some reason you annotated the key filds in your struct with lowercased names of XML nodes while your XML data actually has them uppercased; hence the XML decoder does not "see" your nodes. Removing the `xml:` tags from the fields makes the code work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The problems

There are two problems:

1. The error `xml.Unmarshal` returns is ignored but the function fails on the specified input data stream because the so-called XML declaration (that `<?xml ... ?>` bit) declares the data stream is encoded using an encoding different from UTF-8—the only valid encoding specified by the standard¹,—and so the decoder just refuses to proceed.
2. The fields of the `struct` type to receive the decoded bits of data are annotated with tags hinting the XML decoder that the XML nodes it has to find in the data stream have all-lowercase names which is not true.

   Since the decoder was explicitly told to, say, look for a node named "freetext" it ignores the nodes named "FreeText", and so on.

### The solutions

#### Names of the XML nodes and `struct` tags

The problem of detecting the nodes of interest is the simples to solve: just remove the `xml:` tags and the decoder will be able to find the correct nodes.

An alternative solution is to exploit the decoder's ability to understand "nested" names in field tags: you may remove an extra nested data type by using

```golang
type DimensionInfo struct {
    FreeText []string `xml:"Answer>FreeText"`
}
```

This tag tells the decoder to populate the `FreeText` field with the contents of any node named `FreeText` which is located directly under any node named `Answer`.

#### The encoding of the source data

The problem with encoding is more cumbersome—in the general case.

Since the only valid encoding for representing XML documents is UTF-8 (without BOM), the decoder expects its source data to be UTF-8-encoded.

To handle data streams encoded differently, the decoder provides the programmer with a way to specify "an adapter" which would transparently re-encode the input data stream into an UTF-8-encoded data stream which the decoder would then use.

In order to do that, you have to construct (and tweak) an instance of `xml.Decoder` instead of running `xml.Unmarshal` directly (which constructs a throwaway `Decoder` itself internally).

In your case, turning a call to `xml.Unmarshal(data, &t)` into using an explicitly created `xml.Decoder` is simple:

```golang
dec := xml.NewDecoder(bytes.NewReader(data))
if err := dec.Decode(&t); err != nil {
    // handle the error
}
// handle the result
```

The `Decoder`'s field of interest is [`CharsetReader`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Decoder) which is a function, which, if specified, is called to take the source `io.Reader` specified when a `Decoder` was constructed and the character set (encoding) of the source data stream, and returns another `io.Reader` which, when read from, pulls the data from the source reader, re-encodes it from the source encoding to UTF-8 and hands it off to the `Decoder`.

In the general case, you'd probably use several packages from the [`golang.org/x/text/encoding`](https://godoc.org/?q=text/encoding) hierarchy which are able to understand a host of obsolete non-Unicode and Unicode encodings and provide transparent re-encoding from them to UTF-8.

Still, in your simple case it's probably the simplest to 1) rely on the fact ASCII characters are encoded in exactly the same way as their respective Unicode code points are encoded using UTF-8; 2) assume your input data stream is *really* ASCII (and does not contain weird characters with code points in the range [128..255].
In this case we can get away with using the source `io.Reader` without any re-encoding, leading us to the following solution:

```golang
var dec = xml.NewDecoder(bytes.NewReader(data))
dec.CharsetReader = func(charset string, input io.Reader) (io.Reader, error) {
    switch strings.ToLower(charset) {
    case "ascii", "utf-8":
        return input, nil
    default:
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("cannot handle XML encoding: %s", charset)
    }
}
```

#### An example solution

```golang
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "strings"
)

const data = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ASCII"?>
<QuestionFormAnswers xmlns="http://mechanicalturk.amazonaws.com/AWSMechanicalTurkDataSchemas/2005-10-01/QuestionFormAnswers.xsd">
  <Answer>
    <QuestionIdentifier>annotatedResult.boundingBoxes</QuestionIdentifier>
    <FreeText>[{"height":641,"label":"F-22 Raptor","left":82,"top":97,"width":1088}]</FreeText>
  </Answer>
  <Answer>
    <QuestionIdentifier>annotatedResult.inputImageProperties.height</QuestionIdentifier>
    <FreeText>839</FreeText>
  </Answer>
  <Answer>
    <QuestionIdentifier>annotatedResult.inputImageProperties.width</QuestionIdentifier>
    <FreeText>1260</FreeText>
  </Answer>
</QuestionFormAnswers>`

func main() {
    type DimensionInfo struct {
        FreeText []string `xml:"Answer>FreeText"`
    }

    var dec = xml.NewDecoder(strings.NewReader(data))
    dec.CharsetReader = func(charset string, input io.Reader) (io.Reader, error) {
        switch strings.ToLower(charset) {
        case "ascii", "utf-8":
            return input, nil
        default:
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("cannot handle XML encoding: %s", charset)
        }
    }

    var t DimensionInfo

    err := dec.Decode(&t)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(t.FreeText)
}
```

---

¹ Strictly speaking, that is not true: XML processors must understand [UTF-8 and UTF-16](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#charencoding) but UTF-8 is the de-facto standard on the 'net.

Comment: but in this case how do I get inside of [{}], I tried `t.FreeText[0][0]` but im getting different values than expected

Comment: @deku, I don't quite follow. Do you mean you want to interpret the text in `FreeText` as a JSON array?

Comment: I mean, the final output would be `[{"height":641,"label":"F22-Raptor","left":82,"top":97,"width":1088}]` your answer provides me this, but how do I get, `641, 82 , 97` values, that are inside this?  I tried getting it with `t.FreeText[0][0]` but it gives me the byte instead

Comment: Uh, sure it does. The XML is oblivious to any _interpretation_ of the _strings of bytes_ documents in that format contain. So the XML decoder extracted a sequence of bytes (the text) contained in the XML node you asked it about and returned it. Any further interpretation of those bytes is up to you. To me, it looks like a JSON document containing a list with a single element, which is a JSON object with five fields. If my assumption is correct, just decode this chunk of bytes as a JSON document, what's the problem?